# Is this how Simplex Noise works?

Tags: noise

I have done a huge ton of reading up on Simplex Noise now, and after a lot of confusion and headaches I think I am able to form an idea of how Simplex Noise works now.

Am I right, that simplex noise (2D) is just a grid build of Simplexes, in this case triangles, where at every corner of a triangle there is a value between 0 and 1. When you ask the algorithm for a point it'll convert the 2D coordinates to the simplex grid coordinates, interpolate the noise and then return the actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But there is slight mistake. In simplex noise, the resulting value is summed from its contributing coordinates. Perlin noise is using interpolation.

Edit:
If we look at [Simplex noise demystified](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf), then final value is calculated as :

```
return 70.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2);
```

And according to comment, the resulting values are in range [-1;1]

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the value returned can be higher than 1? Or is it literally `(corner1 + corner2 + corner3) / 3`?

Comment: @Binero No and yes, see my edit.

Comment: Is there a reason for it to be -1 to 1 though? I can't see why it shouldn't work with 0 to 1.

Comment: @Binero It is probably because it is easier to compute. You can still transform easily by calculating (x+1)/2 to get it to [0;1] range.